# AWS ubuntu instance connection error: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic)

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu

I created an Ubuntu Instance in AWS.

I created public key, and downloaded .pem file

and tried to ssh connect with vscode.

I wrote .ssh config file as follows.

```
Host AWS
    HostName 13.125.226.*** 
    IdentityFile the absolute local address that .pem file located (starts with /Users)
    User ubuntu
```

But error occurs

```
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic)
```

What solutions will help?

(When I opened .pem file o I created on AWS, "An error has occurred. Unable to import items." message appears (on mac). Would this additional info help?)

Comment: Did you launch the Amazon EC2 instance and only _after_ that did you create the Key? You should create the Key first, and then specify that Key when launching the EC2 instance. The public half of the key will then be copied to the `~/ubuntu/.ssh/authorized_keys` file to permit you to login.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue with changing User value in config file. Since it is Amazon Linux, User should be ec2-user, not ubuntu.

```
Host AWS
    HostName 13.125.226.*** 
    IdentityFile the absolute local address that .pem file located (starts with /Users)
    User ec2-user
```